# Angular: Duplicating Data Issue in Angular Firestore Pagination and InfinityScroll

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, angularfire, ngx-infinite-scroll

I am facing an issue in an Angular application where I use Firestore for paginating and displaying chat messages. The problem arises when a new message arrives (data), and the existing paginated data gets duplicated.

I have implemented a pagination mechanism using Firestore in my Angular application. Initially, I load the first set of messages and display them. When scrolling up, additional messages are paginated and displayed correctly. However, when a new message arrives, the existing paginated messages get duplicated.

Here's a high-level overview of my implementation: [Source Code Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqg18q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.services.ts)

1. Initial load fetches the first set of messages, and `this.allMessage` is updated.
2. When scrolling down, more messages are paginated, and `this.allMessage` is updated again.
3. On receiving a new message, I update `this.nuevosMensajesState.lastVisibleDoc`.
4. The issue occurs when scrolling down after the new message arrives, leading to duplication of messages in `this.allMessage`.

Here's a snippet of my Angular service and component:

First, create two behaviorSubject

The first observable is responsible for listening when I receive new messages

```
private newMensaggesState: State = {
    groupMessageIndex: 1,
    maxMessageSize: 10,
    lastVisibleDoc: null,
    isNewMessageEmit: false,
  };
     private _newMensaggesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<State>(
    this.newMensaggesState
  );
  readonly newMessagesChanged$ = this._newMensaggesSubject
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```

The second observable is responsible for listening when the scroll directive is activated, I manage the scroll with the ngx-infinite-scroll library

```
    private paginatedMessagesStates: State = {
    groupMessageIndex: 1,
    maxMessageSize: 10,
    lastVisibleDoc: null,
    isNewMessageEmit: false,
  };

 private _paginatedMessagesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<State>(
    this.paginatedMessagesStates
  );
  readonly mensagessPaginatedChanged$ = this._paginatedMessagesSubject
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
```

Now, create the separate states, since I need to be listening to the messages in real time and when you page them into a declarative function, the listening is lost, which is why the two states are created. For this reason, I separated the functions into a single responsibility, I did a lot of research on the subject but some in the community mentioned that it is not that easy to do so this was a solution that I found

Then, at the beginning of the component, the first method in the service is called, which obtains the first ten elements and updates when resolved.

```
    this.newMensaggesState.lastVisibleDoc = lastVisibleDoc;
```

So when the scroll directive is called it already has updated both the index group and the last document when it is called, then the message list `this.allMessages` concatenates the result

It brings up the pagination and the list becomes empty because there are no more items to bring, but at that moment a new message is received, that is where the items are duplicated

If someone can help me please, I have been trying in every way I just need to find a way to reset the pagination to avoid this duplication, or some way to control when a new message comes in

I suspect the problem lies in how I handle the state and paginated data when a new message arrives. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this duplication issue.

Thanks in advance for your help! I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a light on the way. Please

firebase-angular version: "^16.0.0"